# Cannot find AWS ElasticCache Configuration Endpoint Ip Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, memcached, local, nat

We would like to use a NAT to connect locally to the ElasticCache Configuration Endpoint (as described in: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Access.Outside.html). But we could't find the IP address and NAT cannot use DNS.

We did manage to map each node IP Address using  NAT, but we would like to connect to the whole cluster at once.

I found another related question in Ask Ubuntu, but no awserws either:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/779961/use-endpoint-instead-of-ip-in-iptables

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a local redis server for development or unit testing.

Create seperate elasticache clusters for test, staging and production environments.

The reason being, it's too much of work to make it work to connect from local machines and secondly, all this work is again not recommended in any case for a production environment as per [AWS documents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Access.Outside.html) itself:

> Limitations
>
> This approach should be used for testing and development purposes
>   only. It is not recommended for production use due to the following
>   limitations:
>
> The NAT instance is acting as a proxy between clients and multiple
>   clusters. The addition of a proxy impacts the performance of the cache
>   cluster. The impact increases with number of cache clusters you are
>   accessing through the NAT instance. The traffic from clients to the
>   NAT instance is unencrypted. Therefore, you should avoid sending
>   sensitive data via the NAT instance. The NAT instance adds the
>   overhead of maintaining another instance. The NAT instance serves as a
>   single point of failure. For information about how to set up high
>   availability NAT on VPC, see High Availability for Amazon VPC NAT
>   Instances: An Example.